Preventing TabView from resetting to first page when one of its pages are deleted
Working on a WatchOS app (on WatchOS 9.1) using SwiftUI and I'd like to use a TabView to create pages the user can scroll through vertically. Alongside this, I want it to be possible to dynamically add new pages to the TabView and also remove pages that have been added. As such, I am using a ForEach loop to render the TabViews content.
However, when deleting any page, the TabView currently automatically resets to the first page when I would want it to instead go to the previous page from the one that was just deleted.
I have this code to demo my approach:
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var page: Int = 0
    @State var pageIds: [Int] = [0]
    
    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $page) {
            ForEach(pageIds, id: \.self) { id in
                VStack {
                    Text("Page \(id)")
                    Button("Delete Page", action: {
                        pageIds.remove(at: pageIds.firstIndex(of: id)!)
                    })
                }.tag(id)
            }
            Button("Add Page", action: {
                pageIds.append((pageIds.last ?? 0) + 1)
            }).tag("test")
        }
        .tabViewStyle(.carousel)
    }
}

I believe the issue is because the ForEach loop's content is being updated, so it is rerendering all of its content, which results in the View to jump back to the first page. Is there a way I can prevent this behaviour so it instead jumps to the previous page?

Does adding page = pageIds.count - 2 before the pageIds.remove(at: pageIds.firstIndex(of: id)!) fix it? I don't have watchOS installed.

This worked thank you. Seems the issue was because page was pointing to an id that no longer existed, it would reset to the first one, so you’re right, the solution is to change it before deleting the page

Using a valid identifier instead of id: \.self should fix it. ForEach is a view not a loop, you need to give it your array of model structs and tell it what the key path to your unique identifier property is or implement Identifiable so it knows to just use \.id. This is easier once you know what model type each page will show.
